# EF Core how to implement dirty reads in EF Core for one read operation?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core

I have a table that has some potential locks during some batch updates. I'm using SqlServer.

I want to allow dirty reads for this one specific read operation. Does this look like the correct implementation? Is there another way to enable [WITH NOLOCK] for one specific operation?

Unfortunately there isn't much documentation I can find on the subject, would appreciate any links with more information.

Are there any potential downfalls to using transactions in this way?

Additionally, is there any way to enable dirty reads on the context for all operations?

```
        public async Task<AppUser> GetUserByIdAsync(string employeeId)
        {

            using var transaction = await _context.Database.BeginTransactionAsync(System.Data.IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted);
            
            var users =  await _context.Users
                .Include(u => u.PositionRoles)
                .ThenInclude(p => p.Role)
                .Include(u => u.UserRoles)
                .ThenInclude(r => r.Role)
                .Include(u => u.TeamRoles)
                .ThenInclude(r => r.Role)
                .Include(u => u.UserLocations)
                .SingleOrDefaultAsync(u => u.EmployeeId == employeeId);

            await transaction.DisposeAsync();

            return users;
        }
```

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/206485/best-situation-to-use-read-uncommitted-isolation-level

Answer (score 1):

[EF Core Interceptors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/interceptors) are very promising for your task.

You can check docs how they modify a command (SQL query) and think how to apply `DbCommandInterceptor` and `.WithTag` to get uncommitted read for specific operations.

For global dirty reads on the context, `DbConnectionInterceptor` looks good.
This one has worked in my tests

```
class ConnectionInterceptor : DbConnectionInterceptor
{
    public override void ConnectionOpened(DbConnection connection, ConnectionEndEventData eventData)
    {
        var command = connection.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = "SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED";
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        base.ConnectionOpened(connection, eventData);
    }

    public override InterceptionResult ConnectionClosing(DbConnection connection, ConnectionEventData eventData, InterceptionResult result)
    {
        var command = connection.CreateCommand();
        //Set default isolation level here
        command.CommandText = "SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED";
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        return base.ConnectionClosing(connection, eventData, result);
    }
}
```